# c++ object member destructor is called and member exist with default values

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, members

I have a B class and it has a class C member. B objects are stored in a vector. Full Code and output as follows:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

#include "C.h"

class B
{
public:
    B( int = 0 );           // constructor
    B( const B& );  // copy constructor
    ~B();           // destructor
    const B &operator=( const B & );    // assignment operator
    C c();          // return C object
    void val( int );// set val
    int val() const;// return val
private:
    C _c;           // C object
    int _val;       // a value
};

#include "B.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

B::B( int val )
{
    _val = val;

    cout << "B constructor called" << endl;
}

B::B( const B &other )
{
    _c = other._c;

    cout << "B copy constructor called" << endl;
}

B::~B()
{
    cout << "B destructor called" << endl;
}

const B &B::operator=( const B &other )
{
    if ( &other != this ) {     // avoid self-assignment

        _c = other._c;
    }

    return *this;
}

C B::c()
{
    return _c;
}

void B::val( int val )
{
    _val = val;
}

int B::val() const
{
    return _val;
}

#ifndef C_H
#define C_H

class C
{
public:
    C();            // constructor
    ~C();           // destructor
    void val( int );// set val
    int val() const;// return val
private:
    int _val;       // a value
};

#endif

#include "C.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

C::C()
{
    _val = 0;

    cout << "C constructor called" << endl;
}

C::~C()
{
    cout << "C destructor called" << endl;
}

void C::val( int val )
{
    _val = val;
}

int C::val() const
{
    return _val;
}

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "B.h"

using namespace std;

const int n = 5;

vector<B> v( n );

int main()
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        v[i] = B( i );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        B &b = v[i];


    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {

        B &b = v[i];

        b.c().val( 5 );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {

        B &b = v[i];

        cout << b.c().val() << endl;
    }

    cin.ignore( 1 );

    return 0;
}

output:

C destructor called
C destructor called
C destructor called
C destructor called
C destructor called
0
C destructor called
0
C destructor called
0
C destructor called
0
C destructor called
0
C destructor called
```

problem: at each cycle C object is destructed and b.c().val() returns with default ( zero ) value.

question: why?

output is belong to last two for.

Comment: And... what problem are you having? Your "question" as it stands is nothing more than a statement

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: **at each cycle C object is destructed and b.c().val() returns with default ( zero ) value.**

Comment: @Kun That is not a question.

Comment: that's a statement, not a question

Comment: please provide a minimal example that actually compiles i.e. get rid of the #include "B.h" stuff and provide a link to an [online compiler](http://liveworkspace.org) with your example

Comment: Re-posting question after it got closed will rather harm you than help you.

Comment: trolling rather than answering question will harm you than help you

Answer (score 2):

Your `B::c` member function returns a `C` by value. That is, it copies the `_c` object that is being held by the `B` object out of the function. You are calling `val` on that copy and do not affect the member `_c`.

Consider the line:

```
b.c().val( 5 );
```

`b.c()` returns a temporary copy of `b`'s `_c` object. You then call `val` on that temporary. Then the temporary is destroyed at the end of the statement. It is this temporary that is being destroyed in each iteration. That temporary is outputting `C destructor called`.

If you want to affect the member `_c`, you'll need to return it by reference:

```
C& B::c()
{
    return _c;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. I'm very new to C++ and sorry for wasting your time

Comment: @Kun I don't find posting on Stack Overflow a waste of my time. I enjoy doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies here:

```
C c();          // return C object
```

In the `B` object. Try to understand what this is doing.